# MongoDB Query Combined with AND & OR Statement

Tags: mongodb

I want to filter the documents having Id = 2 or Name = Aman OR Name = Ishu.
I am writing the following statement for it.
MongoDB is showing Nothing, No Error At all. What is going wrong in the code, Please help me to rectify it!

```
db.Test.find({
    $and : [{$or: [{"Name": "Aman"}, {"Name": "Ishu"}]} ,{"Id": "2"}]
});
```

Comment: You mean you want documents having Id = 2 AND Name = Aman OR Name = Ishu ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.Test.find({
    $or: [$and:[{"Name": "Aman"}, {"Id": "2"}], {"Name": "Ishu"}]
});
```

Comment: Sorry the $and condition here was wrong! Just Checked, this is the right query:

db.Test.find({
   $or: [{"Name": "Aman"}, {"Name": "Ishu"}, {"Id": "2"}]
});